# I am not able see the jar package structure,but there are no errors

Tags: import, jar, package, classpath

I have following import in my class

`import org.apache.commons.lang.exception.ExceptionUtils;`

`ExceptionUtils` is indeed referenced in my class.

`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "An Server Error occured during saving.\n\n" + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e), "Error",**`

But in the classpath i have package `org.apache.commons.lang3`

I am really not sure how this runs and why there are no errors?
I am using Eclipse Indigo

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your Apache Commons Lang .jar file satisfies your `org.apache.commons.lang.exception.ExceptionUtils` import.

Look here:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadapachecommonslangjar.htm

STRONG SUGGESTION:

Take a look inside of your .jar file.  One easy way to do this is with a tool like [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), or [jd-gui](https://github.com/java-decompiler/jd-gui). Another way is to temporarily rename the file from .jar to .zip, and look at its contents in Windows Explorer.

This will show you the packages (directories and subdirectories) and classes inside of the .jar.

Interesting stuff - try it sometime!

Comment: I did look inside the jar and the class exceptionutils.It clearly says
package org.apache.commons.lang3.exception;
Even in my pom the dependency is

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1</version>
  </dependency>
I am confused:(

Comment: Q: What exactly is the name of your Commons Lang.jar? It's included in your class path, correct?  And it contains ExceptionUtils, correct?  Q: Why do you say you have " org.apache.commons.lang3" in your "classpath"?  This is pointless.

Comment: Name of the jar:commons-lang3-3.0.1
It is added as a maven dependency in my pom and the jar contains ExceptionUtils.
I said i have following import
import org.apache.commons.lang.exception.ExceptionUtils;

Comment: OK: I finally understand your question: Q: how can "commons-lang3-3.0.jar" (which only has `org.apache.commons.lang3.*`) satisfy `org.apache.commons.lang.*`?  A: It can't: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/article3_0.html.  You must be bringing in some OTHER, PARALLEL version of Commons Lang into your build.

Comment: ADDITIONAL SUGGESTION: try this command `mvn dependency:tree` to list *ALL* dependencies Maven finds.  Also double-check your build path, and other things in your build environment (for example, Tomcat system libraries if you're building against a Tomcat runtime).

Comment: Thanks a lot.There was a maven dependency that I did not see and it was satisfying org.apache.commons.lang.exception.ExceptionUtils